Determine if two trees are equal in the free quandle
To start we are going to define an "\$\operatorname{FBM}\$" as follows:

Every integer is an \$\operatorname{FBM}\$.
If \$a\$ and \$b\$ are \$\operatorname{FBM}\$s, then \$a \lhd b\$ is an \$\operatorname{FBM}\$.
If \$a\$ and \$b\$ are \$\operatorname{FBM}\$s, then \$a \rhd b\$ is an \$\operatorname{FBM}\$.
Nothing else is an \$\operatorname{FBM}\$.

We could potentially think of these as finite ordered full binary tree where branch nodes are labeled with booleans, and leaf nodes are labeled with integers.
So, for example, \$1 \lhd (2 \rhd 1)\$ is a \$\operatorname{FBM}\$ with 5 nodes (2 branches and 3 leaves).
From here we will give a set of rewrite rules. Each rule can be applied to any part of the \$\operatorname{FBM}\$ which matches and can be applied either forward or backwards.
\begin{align*}
a \lhd (b \lhd c) &\leftrightarrow (a \lhd b) \lhd (a \lhd c)  \tag{$\lhd$ self-distribution} \\
(a \rhd b) \rhd c &\leftrightarrow (a \rhd c) \rhd (b \rhd c)  \tag{$\rhd$ self-distribution} \\
a \lhd (b \rhd a) &\leftrightarrow b  \tag{$\lhd$ cancellation} \\
(a \lhd b) \rhd a &\leftrightarrow b  \tag{$\rhd$ cancellation} \\
a \lhd a &\leftrightarrow a \tag{$\lhd$ idempotence} \\
a \rhd a &\leftrightarrow a \tag{$\lhd$ idempotence} \\
\end{align*}
So for example the following series of rewrites is valid:
\begin{align*}
1 \lhd (2 \lhd 1) &\rightarrow (1 \lhd 2) \lhd (1 \lhd 1) \tag{$\lhd$ self-distribution} \\
&\rightarrow (1 \lhd 2) \lhd 1 \tag{$\lhd$ idempotence}
\end{align*}
Your task is to take two \$\operatorname{FBM}\$s and determine if there is a sequence of these rewrite rules which takes one to the other.
This is code-golf so the goal is to minimize the size of your source code as measured in bytes.
Input
Input is intended to be flexible. You should take input in a tree-like format, or as an a serialized expression representing the \$\operatorname{FBM}\$ (e.g "1 < (2 > 3)" for \$1 \lhd (2 \rhd 3)\$). You may label the branches with any two distinct values, and you may label the leaves with any values so long as:

There are an arbitrarily large number of potential values (although only finitely many can appear in the fintite input)
You use structural rather than referential equality.

For example, integers, positive integer, and strings should all be fine.
You should output one of two distinct values if the input \$\operatorname{FBM}\$s are equivalent under the rewrite rules, and the other if they are not.
Math
As the title hints at this task is actually to determine if two elements of a free quandle are equal.
The rewrite rules provided are not arbitrary, but are in fact the specific laws defining a quandle. Quandles are a relatively rich algebraic structure, and this should allow for some golfing strategies based around properties of quandles.
My testing solution uses one trick, specific to quandles, to solve the problem.
Test cases
Equivalent
10 < (12 < 3) == (10 < 12) < (10 < 3)
(1 > 3) > 9 == (1 > 9) > (3 > 9)
2 < (3 > 2) == 3
(12 < 4) > 12 == 4
4 = (3 < 4) > 3
18 < 18 == 18
29 > 29 == 29
2 < (3 < 2) == (2 < 3) < 2
(( 1 < 2) < 1) > (1 < (2 < 1)) == (1 < (2 < 1))
((1 < 2) < 1) > (1 < (2 < 1)) == (((2 > 1) > 2) < (1 < (2 < 1))) > (2 > (1 > 2))

Inequivalent
1 /= 12
1 < (1 < 2) /= 1 < 2
1 > (2 < 1) /= 2
(6 > 2) < 6 /= 6 > (2 < 6)
((1 < 2) < 1) > (1 < (2 < 1)) /= (((2 > 1) > 2) < (1 < (2 < 1))) > (2 > (1 < 2))


Typo in test case #8? Also, are Polish inputs ok?

@Albert.Lang I don't see any issue with #8? It follows from self-distribution and idempotence: 2  < (3 < 2) = (2 < 3) < (2 < 2) = (2 < 3) < 2. Your answer agrees!

@UnrelatedString I had one of the <s wrong. I fixed it without deleting the comment.

@Albert.Lang I don't know what Polish inputs means, but parsing from a prefix like your answer is fine.

Retina, 97 92 bytes
\d+
0$(*)2
{`{(\w+)<(\w+)}
$1$2$^$1
)`{(\w+)>(\w+)}
$^$2$1$2
¶.+
$^
+`(\d)(_+)(\d)\3\2\1

^¶

Try it online! Link is to test suite that mostly converts from the given format to what the program wants, which is expressions separated by newlines, fully parenthesised using {}s instead of ()s and no spaces. Explanation: Port of @Albert.Lang's Python answer.
\d+
0$(*)2

Convert integers to unary, wrapping them in markers. Wrapping Retina's * operator in $() makes its arguments default to $& and _ respectively, or I could have just written them out as 0$&*_2. (My previous answer wanted to repeat 1, but this caused a problem because Retina tokenises numbers as a single token so e.g. 10*10 becomes 10101010101010101010 but 2*_2 becomes __2.)
{(\w+)<(\w+)}
$1$2$^$1

Convert {a<b} into aba⁻¹, where a⁻¹ is just the reverse of a.
{(\w+)>(\w+)}
$^$2$1$2

Convert {a>b} into b⁻¹ab.
{`
)`

Repeat the above until all of the operators have been processed.
¶.+
$^

Invert the second expression.
+`(\d)(_+)(\d)\3\2\1


Cancel out any a⁻¹a or bb⁻¹ patterns.
^¶

Check that everything was eliminated.

Python, 261 bytes
import re
l=lambda a,b:f'{a} {b} {a[::-1]}'
g=lambda b,a:f'{a[::-1]} {b} {a}'
f=lambda P,o=' ':f(P[1:],o[::-1]+eval(re.sub('(\\d+)','"\\1."',P[0]))+' ')if P else o!=(o:=re.sub(r" (\.?)(\d)"+8*r"(\d?)"+r"(?:\. \.| )\9\8\7\6\5\4\3\2\1 "," ",o))and f([],o)or' '==o

Attempt This Online!
Takes positive integers as atoms and a Polish-ish function notation l(a,b) ~ (a<b) ; g(a,b) ~ (a>b) to represent the input trees.
I'm sure the code can be streamlined ...
How?
Wikipedia says one example of this structure is group conjugation (in the free group). So I translate inputs like \$(a < b)\$ to something like \$ab a^{-1}\$. What we gain by this is that expression normalisation is extremely simple: adjacent inverses cancel and that's it.
Products are written as space separated juxtaposition.
I'm adding a dot at the end of each integer. That way the inverse in the free group can be represented by string reversal for both single integers and products. And normalisation can be done by finding and eliminating two word palindromes.

Why \9\8\7\6\5\4\3\2\1? Does it introduce some limitation?

@l4m2 it does, we can only handle up to eight digit numbers. I seem to remember that a general palindrome finder cannot be done with regex.

@Albert.Lang Certainly not with BRE or ERE but PCRE and .NET can do it.

Charcoal, 120 bytes
Ｆ²«≔υζ≔⟦⟦⁰⟧⟧υＦ⁻Ｓ(≡κ)«≔⊟υι≡⊟υ<⊞υ⁺⁺§υ±¹ι±⮌⊟υ⊞υ⁺⁺±⮌ι⊟υι»¿›κ9⊞⊞Ｏυκ⟦⁰⟧⊞§υ±¹⁺×⊟§υ±¹χＩκ»≔⁺⊟ζ±⮌⊟υυＷ⌊ΦＬυ∧κ⁼§υ⊖κ±§υκ≔Φυ∧⁻λι⁻λ⊖ιυ¬υ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Takes two space- or newline-separated fully parenthesised inputs without spaces. Explanation: Another port of @Albert.Lang's Python answer.
Ｆ²«

Loop through each input.
≔υζ

Save the previous pass, if any.
≔⟦⟦⁰⟧⟧υ

Start parsing with no positive integer so far.
Ｆ⁻Ｓ(

Loop though the next input but ignoring (s as both operators are binary.
≡κ)«

If the next character is a ), then:
≔⊟υι

Get the operator's RHS b.
≡⊟υ<

If the last operator was a <, then...
⊞υ⁺⁺§υ±¹ι±⮌⊟υ

... pop the LHS a and push aba⁻¹.
⊞υ⁺⁺±⮌ι⊟υι

Otherwise pop the LHS a and push b⁻¹ab.
»¿›κ9⊞⊞Ｏυκ⟦⁰⟧

Otherwise if the next character is < or > then push it and start parsing another positive integer.
⊞§υ±¹⁺×⊟§υ±¹χＩκ

Otherwise continue parsing the current positive integer.
»≔⁺⊟ζ±⮌⊟υυ

Invert the second input and concatenate it to the first input.
Ｗ⌊ΦＬυ∧κ⁼§υ⊖κ±§υκ

While the result contains two consecutive values which are negations of each other...
≔Φυ∧⁻λι⁻λ⊖ιυ

... cancel (remove) those two values.
¬υ

Check whether all of the values could be cancelled.

Python3.10, 392 bytes
Perfect use case for match-case.
lambda a,b:f(a)in[b,f(b)]
def f(a,p=[]):
 match a:
  case[b,0,[c,1,B]]if b==B:l=c
  case[[b,0,c],1,B]if f(b)==f(B):l=f(c)
  case[b,0,[c,0,B]]if b==B:l=[[b,0,c],0,B]
  case[b,0,[c,0,d]]if'['!=str(b)[0]:l=[[b,0,c],0,[b,0,d]]
  case[[b,1,c],1,d]:l=[[b,1,d],1,[c,1,d]]
  case[b,_,B]if b==B:l=b
  case _:l=a
 return l if'['!=str(l)[0]else(U if(U:=[f(i)for i in l])==l or U in p+[a]else f(U,p+[U]))

Attempt This Online!
